# Navigation among tab bar items Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab bar Controller containing 5 Tabs and each tab bar item has individual navigation controller like :
[image]
[image]

Now , If i am currently in **viewctrller3** of **navigationctrller3** in **Tab3** and i want to navigate to **viewctrller2** of **navigationctrller1** in **Tab1**  programmatically . Also I've selected the particular **Tab1**  programmatically But i m unable to reach **viewctrller2**  of 
         **navigationctrller1**. Is this feasible ?, If yes , then please elaborate..
Please guys join hands..!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem -- you say you can select the tab 1, so selectedViewController gets you navigation controller 1, and its [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] should get you to view controller 2.

Comment: Yes I can just mean to say that i can select tab item programmatically . But then , how to push directly from my current screen to the viewcontroller2 of navigationcontroller1

Comment: you may be having some action methods to go to that screen from the user actions.. now to do it programmatically just call those action methods.. it will directly take you to that screen..

Comment: Did you look at my edited answer?  Does that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are currently in viewctrller3, I think you should be able to do this:

```
    UITabBarController *tabCont = (UITabBarController *)[self.navigationController parentViewController];
    [tabCont setSelectedIndex:0];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = tabCont.selectedViewController;
    NSarray *newControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[nav1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2],[nav1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],[nav1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1], nil];
    [nav1 setViewcontrollers:newControllers animated:NO];
```

That last line should rearrange the navigation controller's viewControllers so that viewctrller2 is now the top view controller.

Comment: But i wont be having Viewctrller1 and viewctrller2 object reference .

Comment: @itechnician, see my edited answer. I think this should work, if that navigation controller has all 3 of the view controllers you show in your post on its navigation stack.

Comment: Finally , i got solution via your excerpt thx..  
Just convert   UINavigationController *nav1 =  (UINavigationController *)tabCont.selectedViewController;

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is

1. before setting the SelectedIndex of a tabbar , you maintain one reference variable in appDelegate and assign to it the name of the class which is required to be navigated after tab selection.
2. In the delegate of tabbar controller :

   - `(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;`
     check whether the visible controller is kind of class same as the class name that is set in appdelegate reference variable? If yes then nothing to do , if not then check if that controller is in the navigation stack or not? If its there in stack then pop/push to that index controller else create that controller and push to it.

Comment: by setting the selectedIndex of tabbarcontroller this deltegate is not called

Comment: ya ,its not getting called unless user taps the tab bar, then you will need to create a delegate method and call it at the time of programmatically setting tab bar index

Comment: But also the delegate is bruteforce type of solution and i have to check it out in every viewcontroller of 1st navigation controller

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that there will be any issue in this. suppose your nav1 is 1st navigationController.

```
[self.nav1 pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
```

its will have to work for you.

Comment: But its dynamic how can i be sure that everytime its on the 1st viewcontroller of 1st navigationcontroller

Answer (score -1):

From ViewController3 execute..

```
   UINavigationController *navigationController1 =       [appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]; // fetch the navigationController

            [navigationController1 popToViewController:[navigationController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];

            [appDelegate .tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: what is the rootController of your window??